# How to put JSON into a column data if sub-query returns more than 1 row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, database

I want to select portfolio of user with the same query that i used for select users.

Here the example that i want.

User Table

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
UID     NAME        USERNAME        EMAIL       PASSWORD        STATUS
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       Manoj       manoj           a@a.com     ********        1
2       Test U      testing         b@a.com     ********        1
3       Company     user            c@a.com     ********        1
4       Agency      company         d@a.com     ********        1
```

User table in my database
[image: User Table in my Database]

Portfolio Table

```
-----------------------------------
PID     UID     TITLE       STATUS
-----------------------------------
1       1       title 1     1
2       1       title 2     1
3       1       title 3     1
4       2       title 1     1
```

Portfolio Table in my database
[image: Portfolio Table]
**Result I want**

```
----------------------------------
UID     USERNAME        PORTFOLIO
----------------------------------
1       manoj           JSON OBJECT OF PID (1,2,3)
2       testing         JOSN OBJECT OF PID (4)
3       user            NULL
4       company         NULL
```

Currently I'm trying to use

```
SELECT u.uid,u.username,(SELECT * FROM portfolio p WHERE u.UID=p.UID) as portfolio FROM users u
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A bit convoluted, but you could create JSON objects for each row, concatenate them using `GROUP_CONCAT` and cast the result (wrapped in `[]` to make it an array) to JSON;

```
SELECT u.uid, u.username, 
  CASE WHEN p.uid IS NULL 
       THEN NULL 
       ELSE CAST(CONCAT('[',
                   GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('pid', p.pid,
                                            'title', p.title, 
                                            'status', p.status)),     
                 ']') AS JSON) END portfolios
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN portfolio p
  ON u.uid=p.uid
WHERE p.status = 1
GROUP BY u.uid, u.username;
```

...which gives...

```
+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | manoj    | [{"pid": 1, "title": "title 1", "status": 1}, {"pid": 2, "title": "title 2", "status": 1}, {"pid": 3, "title": "title 3", "status": 1}] |
|    2 | testing  | [{"pid": 4, "title": "title 1", "status": 1}]                                                                                           |
|    3 | user     | NULL                                                                                                                                    |
|    4 | company  | NULL                                                                                                                                    |
+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you're using an older MySQL without JSON support, you could build it as a string;

```
SELECT u.uid, u.username, 
  CASE WHEN p.uid IS NULL
  THEN NULL 
  ELSE CONCAT('[', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{ "pid":',p.pid,',"title":"', REPLACE(p.title, '"', '\\"'),
           '","status":',p.status, ' }')), ']') END portfolios
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN portfolio p 
  ON u.uid=p.uid AND p.status=1
GROUP BY u.uid, u.username;
```

...which will give you...

```
+------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| uid  | username | portfolios                                                                                                                   |
+------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | manoj    | [{ "pid":2,"title":"title 2","status":1 },{ "pid":3,"title":"title 3","status":1 },{ "pid":1,"title":"title 1","status":1 }] |
|    2 | testing  | [{ "pid":4,"title":"title 1","status":1 }]                                                                                   |
|    3 | user     | NULL                                                                                                                         |
|    4 | company  | NULL                                                                                                                         |
+------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Showing me this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON)" and also i want to select portfolio only that have status = 1

Comment: @ManojKumar Which MySQL version are you running? Only version 5.7.8 and higher support JSON natively.

Comment: Okey.. i am using "5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.04.1"

Comment: @ManojKumar Updated the answer with a string building version that does not use the built in JSON support.

Comment: We can also get portfolio of in foreach loop of user. Which is the good practice getting. Getting portfolio in foreach or with a single query that you have explained. @Joachim Lsaksson

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL 8: With [`JSON_OBJECTAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) and [`JSON_OBJECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) functions**

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id,
    u.username,
    CASE WHEN p.user_id IS NULL
        THEN NULL 
    ELSE 
        JSON_OBJECTAGG(
            IF(p.portfolio_id IS NULL, '', p.portfolio_id ), 
            JSON_OBJECT('title', p.title, 'status', p.status)) END portfolios
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN portfolio AS p ON u.user_id = p.user_id AND p.status = 1
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

**Result:**

```
+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_id | username | portfolios                                                                                                               |
+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       1 | manoj    | {"1": {"title": "title 1", "status": 1}, "2": {"title": "title 2", "status": 1}, "3": {"title": "title 3", "status": 1}} |
|       2 | testing  | {"4": {"title": "title 1", "status": 1}}                                                                                 |
|       3 | user     | NULL                                                                                                                     |
|       4 | company  | NULL                                                                                                                     |
+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

as of 5.7 use

```
JSON_OBJECT('key1', 1, 'key2', 'abc');
```

Its way less complicated than multiple concat statements and has the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

Use `group_concat`

```
select UID,USERNAME,concat('JSON OBJECT OF PID (',group_concat(PID),')') PORTFOLIO 
from User u join Portfolio p
on u.UID=p.UID group by UID
```

or try this :-

```
SELECT u.UID,NAME,concat('JSON OBJECT OF PID (',group_concat(pid),')') 
FROM `User` u LEFT join Portfolio p
on u.UID=p.UID group by u.UID
```

Comment: This will not return JSON data it simply add comma separated values of columns from the portfolio table in PORTFOLIO column and also i want to put condition on select of portfolio where status = 1

Comment: what you need ? can you plz show some sample data @ManojKumar

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the question from phpmyadmin @rahautos