# MySQL+PHP: Get group of photos of each single objects of other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically, I have two tables: **objects** and **pictures**

For each objects, users could upload some photos. (max 6)

So... For each upload I save picture into table **pictures**

Example

**Objects**
id=1, name=shoes, data_creation=1234

and

**Uploads**

id=1, obj_id = 1, url=LINK1

id=2, obj_id = 1, url=LINK2

id=3, obj_id = 1, url=LINK3

---

So, I need to select all that I need in one single query... Is it possible?

The best thing would be merge photos like array... so the returing feching should be like this

id=1, name=shoes, photos=[url1,url2,url3]

or... even better

id=1, name=shoes, photos=[{src=LINK1,caption=CAPTION1},{src=LINK2,caption=CAPTION2},{src=LINK3,caption=CAPTION3}]

There's a way to do that in MySQL+Php?

I tried with inner join/left join but this return object information for each picture found.

Please help me... I'm going crazy :D

Comment: Proper way is to use one query but possibly 1 row for each photo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put JSON into a column data if sub-query returns more than 1 row in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350058/how-to-put-json-into-a-column-data-if-sub-query-returns-more-than-1-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create a query that joins the two tables.
Ex:

```
SELECT Objects.name, Uploads.url FROM Objects INNER JOIN Uploads ON Object.id = Uploads.obj_id
```

This will return 3 rows, one per "Uploads" item with Objects.name repeated. It's up to you to normalize this array to your need.

If you want something that maps your results and gives you an "Objects" object with 3 "Uploads" as properties you have to take a look at some "Object Relational Mapping" (ORM) software. See Doctrine for example.