# Grouping by with the query builder as if it were a collection

Tags: php, sql, laravel, group-by

I am working on a Laravel app that needs to do a `groupBy` on a set of items like `groupBy` does on a collection however doing this on collection after getting the data will not work as I need to slim down the results with query builder and after that the `groupBy` won't do anything useful. I understand that the query builder `groupBy` and the collection `groupBy` do different things. Is there a way to do what the `groupBy` on a collection does with the query builder or `SQL`?

I've been googling various things, playing with queries, and asking `Bard` but came up with nothing it seems the `sql` group by does things differently.

Comment: Can you provide an example of some data and what you want it to look like?  `GROUP BY` in SQL is designed to be used by aggregate functions (SUM/AVG/MAX, etc.) so it's probably the wrong approach if you want all the rows.

Comment: I have a table like `sensor_id=606,value=2,set_id=someid`. I need to select every 50th row but before that, they need to be grouped by 'set_id' like on a collection.

Comment: Is there a reason you want every 50th row after grouping? Is there something special about the 50th record in each group or is it an arbitrary 1 in 50? I ask because you could achieve something similar by doing a select distinct on 'set_id' then joining the rest back in with a subquery and a limit possibly with a random order

Answer (score 1):

To the question:

"Is there a way to do what the groupBy on a collection does with the query builder or SQL?"

The short answer is no.

SQL can only give back a two dimensional set of results. It may help to think of `GROUP BY` more as an aggregation than actually grouping.

With Laravel's collections the group method takes records that share the value you're grouping by and organises the collection into a series of sub-collections. It only cares about the data it's grouping by.

With SQL it's more a case of merging a number of records into a single row, it needs to know what to do with the ungrouped values. Let's say you have a table of addresses:

| city | street | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | Oxford Street | 100 |
| London | Oxford Street | 101 |
| London | Carnaby Street | 200 |
| London | Carnaby Street | 201 |
| Bristol | Corn Street | 302 |

If I group by City, SQL wants to give me back two records (London and Bristol) so I need to either aggregate the remaining columns with something like `GROUP_CONCAT()` or `MAX()` or further divide the results by adding them to the group parameters.

If I group by City **and** Street then it wants to give me 3 records (London/Oxford Street, London/Carnaby Street and Bristol/Corn Street) so I only need to aggregate the number column.

The **long** answer is yes but you'd have to manipulate your grouped data into json objects so you can return a single value for each row's column.
See: [How to put JSON into a column data if sub-query returns more than 1 row in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350058/how-to-put-json-into-a-column-data-if-sub-query-returns-more-than-1-row-in-mysql)

It sounds like you need to get your filters set up on the query so you can limit your result set before using the collection to group the results

Answer (score 1):

The original question doesn't cover the full context, but it sounds like your goal is to select every 50th record for each `set_id` in a table.  This is achievable in SQL directly, but it's not exactly straightforward.

For consistent results, you'll need to add an `ORDER BY`.  This is important since *generally* MySQL will return things sorted by primary key, but it's not a guarantee.

The query you're trying to come up with looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  t.sensor_id, 
  t.value, 
  t.set_id 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    sensor_id, 
    value, 
    set_id, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY set_id ORDER BY some_column_here) as rn
  FROM 
    your_table
) as t 
WHERE t.rn % 50 = 0; # Assuming you literally meant every 50th row. Otherwise just use "= 50" instead.
```

Which should convert to a query something like this in Laravel:

```php
$results = DB::table('your_table')
    ->select('sensor_id', 'value', 'set_id')
    ->selectRaw('ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY set_id ORDER BY some_ordering_column) as rn')
    ->fromSub(function ($query) {
        $query->from('your_table')->selectRaw('sensor_id, value, set_id');
    }, 't')
    // Replace with `where->('rn', 50)` if you just want the 50th record, not every 50th.
    ->whereRaw('rn % 50 = 0')
    ->get();
```